# TypeScript - Extending a Type by providing a different value for a property

Tags: typescript

I have one Type:

```
export type EventItemType = {
  Id: string;
  Event?: any;
};
```

I then have another Type, which will eventually be the value of `EventItemType.Event`:

```
export type FooEvent = {
  Amount: number;
};
```

The final object will be:

```
{
    Id: 123,
    Event: {
        Amount: 1
    }
}
```

Later on, I'm iterating over an array of these objects:

```
events.map((event: EventItemType) => {
    return {
        someOtherKey: event.Event.Amount <-- how do I get TS to know this `Event` is of Type `FooEvent`
    }
})
```

I have a bunch of objects created as `EventItemTypes`, but I can't know the `Event?: any;` Type at that time, only when I define the `FooEvent` Type. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// introduce generic type parameter Event
export type EventItemType<Event> = {
  Id: string;
  Event?: Event;
};

export type FooEvent = {
  Amount: number;
};

// initialization with specific FooEvent
const events: EventItemType<FooEvent>[] = [];
events.map((event) => {
    return {
        someOtherKey: event.Event?.Amount // nicely shows proper type
    }
})
```

Eventually you can do following in order to keep `any` in the orginal type:

```
export type EventItemType = {
  Id: string;
  Event?: any;
};

export type FooEvent = {
  Amount: number;
};
// function which takes array of some type T extending EventItemType
function processEvents<T extends EventItemType, F extends (event: T) => any>
(events: T[], f: F) { return events.map(f) };

const events = [{Id: '1', Event: {Amount: 1} as FooEvent}]
processEvents(events, event => ({
  someKey: event.Event?.Amount // works nicely
}))
```

The main difference is that in the second solution we have very polymorphic behavior, and second function argument will adjust to the type of given array.

The core for working inference is:

- `T extends EventItemType` we say we get types which are not equal but extend `EventItemType` and it means TS will narrow our `Event: any` into given by argument type
- `F extends (event: T) => any` given function works with `T` but has also not specified output, but thanks to `extend` function output will also be narrowed

Comment: The first approach is already polymorphic in the `Event` property. The second one has just a type hole IMO.

Comment: Second allows you to stay with the original type but still have narrowing to wanted type

Comment: And what do you mean by type hole?

Comment: you're not actually testing if the Event is a FooEvent. You should be using a Type Predicate to accurately know if it's a FooEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Type Predicate.

It will teach your typescript that a type can be narrowed down in two ways:

- a desirable way in your true branch
- an undesirable way in the false branch.

Some general rules:

- never use `as` (unless you're returning a mutated object from a function all the time).
- never use `any` (just no.).

```
class FooEvent extends Event {
    public type = 'Foo'
    public Amount = 0
}

type SomeKindOfEvent = Event | FooEvent;

const id = () => id.count++
id.count = 0;

const makeEventItem = (event: SomeKindOfEvent) => ({
    Id: id(),
    Event: event
})

export type EventItemType<Event> = {
  Id: string;
  Event?: Event;
};


// this is the only place i would find it acceptable to use "any" (in place of SomeKindOfEvent)
function isFooEvent (event: SomeKindOfEvent): event is FooEvent {
    if ('Amount' in event) 
        return typeof event.Amount === 'number';

    return false
}


const fooEvents = [
    makeEventItem(new Event('Something')),
    makeEventItem(new FooEvent('SomethingSomethingSomethingDarkside')),
].map((event) => {
    return {
        amount: isFooEvent(event.Event) && event.Event.Amount || 0
    }   
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28CiA3ApgOwC7TQDy0wBMZVMcBvAKGlugAcBXAIxAEthosBPetaALzQA5AnjCadJqw7QAggFt4jbIOgAGKgF8qVHn2gBleArQBpNhiIB5AGZlVQhzgA+cRM4Dcu4PAwQcNiI1AAoASkEAPmgggDpfFSwAaiSqOITHDW8qX38cBTAAazRnAElCBVC0dGwALiMTc0sbexqsCIFokOo6aFKieqDwgBpJWmd66vJtMN18engAJxx9fjKKgBVeNAAeZ2ihHr6B6ADFywBzb3G2gH56r21sqgB6F64ACzYYb8-+PxA3AY4GA-DY0AA7soQMFbM0YjgwMBQfQsGBWPwsPBoIwIPwAERgDDcfHQEKWYFI-62BqmCxWOzOWa2FTALBsPwxCBiZxkqZ1WlNBmtchhSZtLnuZASo60Ng0kLCRTKbDCGIYXBtCJjXrQRZoLCMRYa1bwGn8rCxZWJQQCITCDCMBTMNCLYTZXr6w3G6C2MAgPHaXQ5PwBX0eNowIQAbR1BWK6zQChCGDQEOgzkVxlMWC+GAuwjCYVGvXjJTa5STKbTUszwmzBrzFwbucuLabABEwItChAgmhC8WqABdWIFeghEIWjrRWV6g1GjVz3pgJSJQbciPkKdtWJM6AAMgPmvIe931tULjcml6WjoMyAA)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the type **FooEvent** on **EventItemType.Event** as below:

```
export type FooEvent = {
  Amount: number;
};

export type EventItemType = {
  Id: string;
  Event?: FooEvent; // <--- Event can be undefined or FooEvent
};
```

Now if we take a look at your code below you stil gonna have a typing error.
Because  **event.Event** can be **undefined** or **FooEvent** you cannot access the **Amount** property.
You have check first that **event.Event** is not undefined

```
events.map((event: EventItemType) => {
  /**
  return {
      someOtherKey: event.Event.Amount // Error because Event may be undefined
  }
  */

 let someOtherKey = null;

 if(event.Event !== undefined) {
   someOtherKey = event.Event.Amount;
 }

 return {
   someOtherKey
 };

})
```

There is also a faster and dirtiest way to solve your problem but only use it if
you are 100% sure that the type of **event.Event** is FooEvent.

**WARNING:** this may lead to runtime errors  !
I

```
events.map((event: EventItemType) => {
  return {
    someOtherKey: (event.Event as FooEvent).Amount 
  }
})
```